# SharePoint Framework AadHttpClient - operation is part of experimental feature

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying to use the AadHttpClient library that comes with SPFx to connect to a custom API secured by an app registration in Azure AD.

However when I run the web part in the workbench, SharePoint Online (in the tenant _layouts) I get an error in the console saying that the feature is experimental.

`Error: The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that is not supported in the current environment.`

As far as I can make out from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad), it should be in general release.

> When connecting to Azure AD-secured APIs, we recommend that you use the MSGraphClient and AadHttpClient classes, which are **now generally available**. For more information about the recommended models, see Connect to Azure AD-secured APIs in SharePoint Framework solutions and Use the MSGraphClient to connect to Microsoft Graph.

When I go to the API management page in SP Admin site I get a popup stating

> ***Access to Azure Active Directory resources using the SharePoint Framework will be available soon.

So I'm a bit confused.

I also get an error on the API management page saying..

> A null value was found with the expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.

I also get the same error when I try in PowerShell running

```
Get-SPOTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequests
```

I'm not 100% sure I understand the relevance of the API management page - does an admin need to approve just once for the web part then all users are good to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue. The github thread can be found [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2472). What fixed it for me was adding the account I was using as a site collection admin.

```
Connect-SPOService
Set-SPOUser -Site https://TENANT-admin.sharepoint.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True -LoginName yourLoginName
```